# Is there any possibilities to make an app that open even if the phone is lock?

Tags: android

I need to make an app that will open even if the screen is locked. Is there any possibilities to make this?

Comment: How the app should executed? By an event? Which one?

Comment: use AlarmMAnager to popup your screen on top of lock screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) it runs of top of lock screen like a Default alarm application,we can have the access of GUI even if phone is locked.

see [this tutorial](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist) for sample application which uses [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class

Comment: How can put an extra button on notification bar(just like wifi,screen orientation)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can launch your app when phone is lock.

Android only allow to run a **Service in background** and get **Notification** even your phone is locked.

That is my opinion might be some expert can know how to achieve this.

Open to update my answer.

Comment: How can put an extra button on notification bar(just like wifi,screen orientation)? Is it possible?

Comment: no that is not possible.you can just redirect you activity via pending intent.